# ClassNotFoundException: org hibernate.collection.PersistentSet + Hibernate 5.4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jms, weblogic

We are migrating from hinernate 3 to 5.4. After making all the changes the module was working fine, so i merged the code other fixes.

Post this i am getting this strange exception for some of the messages while others are processing.

Tried to find out the root cause but not able to find out **why it's referring hibernate 3 class.**. The Object we are sending has a one-to-many relation

Our application is reading messages from JMS queue, in the  below, it is raising the exception though nowhere I have used this class

```
Serializable obj =((ObjectMessage) message).getObject()
```

Exception: sorry can not add the whole trace

```
Weblogic.jms.common.JMSException[JMSClientExceptions:055115]Error deserializing an object
. 
. 
. 
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org hibernate.collection.PersistentSet
```

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml

Comment: @Anish B. We are not using maven. The code build using Ant and deployed the jar in weblogic

Comment: Can check whether the jars are updated or not ? Redo ant build

Comment: I can see the hibernate 5.4 jar, and Hibernate 3 jar is not there. The same code i deployed in another server and there i didnt see that exception so confused what is happening.

Comment: where the server is ?

Comment: Can you check the server logs ?

Comment: While merging the code, you may have forgotten to change the code somewhere. Plz check.

Comment: This a client machine, so i can not share the exact log. I can see the exception that i mentioned raising from the line Serializable object.

Comment: In my code nowhere i am using this class.

Comment: One thing, can you copy the server from there ?

Comment: No i can not share anything here

Comment: No, you check on your system that I was telling.